# Reducing the number of parameters in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the (dimensionless) ODE
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = ay-by^2-\frac{y^2(y-c)}{1-y}.
\end{equation}

Is it possible to reduce the number of parameters in this ODE to two? I have tried introducing the scalings $y=\nu Y$ and $x=\xi X$ where the new variables are $Y$  and $x$, however, I can't seem to eliminate any of the original parameters. Someone suggested I try the transformation
\begin{equation}
X=f(x), \tag{1}
\end{equation}
but I'm not so sure about this.

Are there any general methods to reduce the complexity/number of parameters in an ODE along the lines of equation (1)?

Answer (score 0):

You have,
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= ay -by^2 -\frac{y^2(y-c)}{1-y}$$
$$=\frac{(b-1)y^3+(c-b-a)y^2+ay}{(1-y)}$$
$$=\frac{\alpha y(y^2 +\frac{\beta}{\alpha}y + \frac{a}{\alpha})}{(1-y)}$$
$$\alpha=b-1$$
$$\beta=c-b-a$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\alpha y(y-r_1)(y-r_2)}{(1-y)}$$
$$r_{1,2}=\frac{\beta}{2\alpha} \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}-\frac{4a}{\alpha}}$$
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\int \frac{(1-y)dy}{y(y-r_1)(y-r_2)}=\int dx$$
Expand the denominator in partial fractions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but you still have 3 parameters in line 6: $\alpha,\,\beta$ and $a$.